# How to call method of an instance in python

Tags: python

I am having an issue calling a method in a very simple python class.  I have something that looks like this:

```
from shape import Shape

class Figure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shapes = []  # the shape objects that make up self

        self.shape0 = shape([1, 3, 2], [30, 20])
        self.shape1 = shape([2, 3, 4], [25, 35])



    def get_points(self):
        # Returns all .points of all members of self.shapes
        all_points = self.shape0
        all_points.extend(self.shape1)
        print(all_points)

get_points()
```

In get_points I'm trying to create a list of all of the instances of shape whether they be squares, pentagons, or anything. Right now, they are only triangles (the first array is a label of their points, the second is the angle of two of their vertices).

I'm currently trying to test if all_points returns a list of all of the points in both triangles (so 1,2,3,4).  But currently, I'm getting an error trying to call get_points().  Does anyone know why I can't call get_points() right here? Error says, 'Unresolved reference 'get_points'.

Comment: You need an instance of your class.

Comment: So like self.get_points()?

Comment: `x = Figure(); x.get_points()`

Comment: Your class isn't doing much. `self.shapes` isn't used, and and assuming `shape` even has an `extend` method, `get_points` could more simply be implemented as `return [self.shape0, self.shape1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @chepner.  Do you know how I also might get the first list of each shape to return in get_points?

Comment: Not without seeing the definition of `shape`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `Figure` first.

```
f = Figure()
f.get_points()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of `Figure` to call the method upon:

```
f = Figure()
print f.get_points()
```